# Use Spark fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 with AWS Glue

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I haven't been able to figure this out, but I'm trying to use a direct output committer with AWS Glue:

`spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2`

Is it possible to use this configuration with AWS Glue?

Comment: moku just check my answer hope it helps you! one thing is spark.hadoop is not needed since we are directly using hadoopConfiguration so configuration would be `mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version` instead of `spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version`

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Haven’t had a chance to test. I will be sure to leave feedback and/or check your answer if it indeed is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Option 1 :***

Glue uses spark context you can set hadoop configuration to aws glue as well. since internally dynamic frame is kind of dataframe.

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mykey","myvalue")
```

I think you neeed to add the correspodning class also like this

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapred.output.committer.class", "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter")
```

example snippet :

```
 sc = SparkContext()

    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version","2")

    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
```

***To prove that that configuration exists ....***

*Debug in python :*

```
sc._conf.getAll() // print this
```

*Debug in scala :*

```
sc.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)
```

***Option 2:***

Other side you try using job parameters of the glue :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html
which has key value properties like mentioned in docs

```
'--myKey' : 'value-for-myKey'
```

you can follow below screen shot for editing job and specifying the parameters with `--conf`

[image]

***Option 3:***
If you are using, aws cli you can try below...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html

Fun is they mentioned in the docs ***dont set*** message like below. but i dont know why it was exposed.

[image]

> To sum up : I personally prefer ***option1*** since you have
>   programmatic control.

Answer (score 0):

Go to glue job console and edit your job as follows :

> Glue> Jobs > Edit your Job> Script libraries and job parameters
> (optional) > Job parameters

Set the following:

> key: --conf  value:
>
> spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2