# Unable to find the written file on disk

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs, aws-glue

I am using AWS GLUE to trigger a job. The job reads a .csv file from S3 and then writes on disk. I have read the csv file into a dynamic DATAFRAME using the following piece of code:

```
dydf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = 's3',
    connection_options = {'paths': ['s3://some-bucket/test.csv']},
    format = 'csv')
```

Then I convert dydf to a spark DataFrame like this:

```
sdf = dydf.toDF()
sdf.show()
```

Next step is to write `sdf` to disk using the following piece of code:

```
sdf.coalesce(1).write.csv('tmp/test.csv')
```

The above piece of code does not throw any error as the following piece of `print("written successfully")` statement is executed successfully.
When I run `os.listdir('tmp/')` I don't see any test.csv nor do I see a test.csv folder.

Also, going through the logs I can see the following message:

**output.DirectFileOutputCommitter (DirectFileOutputCommitter.java:isDirectWrite(162)) - Direct Write: DISABLED**

Any pointers?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432696/use-spark-fileoutputcommitter-algorithm-version-2-with-aws-glue