# Unable to write csv file to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue-spark

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

df = spark.read.csv("s3://bucket1/file1.csv", header=True)
df.show(5)

df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("s3://bucket1/file2.csv", header=True)
```

The write to S3 does not work. I see the following statement in the logs,

> INFO DirectFileOutputCommitter: Direct Write: DISABLED

As suggested in [Use Spark fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 with AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432696/use-spark-fileoutputcommitter-algorithm-version-2-with-aws-glue), I tried after adding the following,

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapred.output.committer.class", "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
```

It did not help. What am i missing here?

Comment: Do you need to indicate `"s3:file2.csv"` for writing to S3? PS I think the general guidance is to use `s3a` rather than `s3`.

Comment: @jarmod s3a or s3... either way i get the same error

Comment: perhaps follow the link in comment of this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403370/unable-to-find-the-written-file-on-disk

Comment: @Emma I tried it. It did not help

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432696/495455 (always helps to put your research)

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes I have mentioned the same link in the question